# Rescaling and Image Padding Issues with GraphicsRow

Tags: plotting, legending, graphics

I am trying to get a row of plots (which include legends and labels) using GraphicsRow, with vertical heights of the plots equal. I manually set the size and image padding of these plots so that the plots take up the same vertical space

```
verticalSize = 250;
p1 = Plot[Evaluate@Table[Cos[n x], {n, 1, 4}], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
           Frame -> True, RotateLabel -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
           PlotLegends -> 
           Placed [Map[StringReplace["n= x", "x" -> ToString[#, InputForm]] &,
           Table[n, {n, 1, 4}]], {Scaled[{0, 1}], {-0.1, 1.01}}], 
           Epilog -> Inset[Text[Style["(a)", 16]],
           ImageScaled[{0.9, 0.9}], Alignment -> Center], 
           ImageSize -> {Automatic, verticalSize}, 
           ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {35, 4}}]

 p2 = Plot[Evaluate@Table[(1/(\[Sigma] Sqrt[
            2 Pi])) Exp[-0.5 (x/\[Sigma])^2], {\[Sigma], 1, 4}], {x,-10, 10},Frame -> True, 
        FrameLabel -> 
{"x", "\[LeftBracketingBar]\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(
[CapitalPsi]\), \
\(0\)]\)(x; \[Sigma])\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[RightBracketingBar]\), \
\(2\)]\)"},                                       
            RotateLabel -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
            PlotLegends -> 
            Placed [Map[
            StringReplace["\[Sigma]= x", "x" -> ToString[#, InputForm]] &, 
            Table[n, {n, 1, 4}]], {Scaled[{0, 1}], {-0.1, 1.01}}],
            Epilog -> 
            Inset[Text[Style["(b)", 16]], ImageScaled[{0.9, 0.9}], 
            Alignment -> Center], ImageSize -> {Automatic, verticalSize}, 
            ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {35, 4}}]
```

This produces plots

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ideally, I want to see these exact images at the size I see in the output cell side-by-side in one graphic. However, when I come to using Graphics Row, the output shows that the overall image size and the image padding have been altered

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't `Row`  be enough for the job?

```
row = Row[{p1, p2}]
```

To export,
simply type

```
Export["row.pdf",row]
```

[image]

You might want to move the labels in the second picture to RHS.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said: I then want to export the figure to pdf for use in a LaTex document

Comment: Sure, it is straightforward. The output file should be a pdf with a vector graphic.

Comment: Doing as you suggested gives this ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo220.png) . How can I export it and retain the Frame, ticks and relative positions of the plots?

Comment: Interesting. In my case, this is the procedure I use all the time when using pdfs. No idea why in your case it does not work with pdfs (i'm using linux and windows).

Comment: I'm using Mac and version 11.1.1, so perhaps that's it?

Comment: @oweydd, adjust the size of your notebook before exporting. The result of the first line (`row = ...` ) should fit the notebook width.

Comment: The solution to `Row` adding a newline when exporting wide graphics is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183728/5115), and it is to use `Style` like this: `Export["test.pdf", Style[ Row[ ... ], LineBreakWithin->False]];`