# Mathematica exporting issues with Row[]

Tags: plotting, export, image, pdf-format

I've had this issue for quite awhile - and it's quite frustrating. When publishing papers, we try to get all of our figures in .pdf for obvious reasons. Usually, Mathematica exports to .pdf just fine, except when you have plots in a Row[]. For example:

```
testplot=Row[{
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
        FrameLabel -> {"y", "x"}, ImagePadding -> {{100, 0}, {100, 0}}, 
        BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 30, FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
        LabelStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> 900],

   Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"y", "x"}, ImagePadding -> {{0, 1}, {100, 0}}, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 30, FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
    LabelStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> 800]
   }]

Export["~/Desktop/test.pdf", testplot]
Export["~/Desktop/test.png", testplot]
```

Should produce a nice side-by-side plot, where each plot uses the same y-axis. The .png output looks fine:

[image: Test .png output]

While the .pdf output messes up and wraps the second plot:

[image: messed up .pdf output]

Has anyone seen this issue before? I've tried everything I can think of, but .pdf export just will not export side-by-side images!

Thanks in advance,
Zack

Comment: Does `GraphicsRow` not work?

Comment: When you export to PDF, your image width specify printers points at 72 per inch.  If you want to put two figures side by side, set their widths to 216 each.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style) wrapper to prevent line breaks:

```
Export["pdftest.pdf", Style[testplot, LineBreakWithin->False]];
```

Comment: Thank you Carl!!